# Where is the Deployement Screen

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I am trying to keep my application in the background on the iOS platform using firemonkey.

I have came across an answer witch tells me how to make the application remain in background.

Here is the answer:

> You'll need to copy the info.plist file and modify it using a unix EOL
>   friendly editor (such as Notepad++). Add the following lines to it:
>
> UIBackgroundModes  voip
>
> In the Deployment screen for your project, uncheck the original
>   .info.plist, and add the copy you modified. Note that if you
>   change any project options that changes the original, you'll need to
>   go thru this process again, or just reflect the changes in the
>   modified file.

How ever I can't figure out where is the Deployment screen. Does anybody know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(NOTE: I don't do iOS development, so this info is based on some quick experimentation with a new iOS FMX project in XE5.)

Those instructions are for XCode, which isn't Delphi. Delphi doesn't have the XCode deployment screen.

The Delphi equivalent is in Project->Deployment from the IDE main menu. You can locate the `.plist` file in the `Local Name` column, in the form `YourProject.info.plist`. I think the original copy is actually generated when you build your project for deployment (either Release or Debug) to the simulator or device, so you may have to do that first in order to find it.

If you look at the samples for XE5 (which seems to be the one in `Samples\Delphi\DataSnap\connectors\iOSClients\client_company_tweet`), you can see where they're located once the file has been generated.

Comment: As well as answering the question, you should check the tags. In this case the question is missing the Delphi tag and it should be added.